# Can not find entrance to Korvanjund during the quest "The Jagged Crown"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I started the civil war quests a while ago and never finished them because they were time consuming and quite boring to be honest. I am in the imperial legion. So for I while I stopped but then I started doing it again. Currently, I am on the quest, The Jagged Crown, which takes place in Korvanjund. I'm supposed to follow legate Rikke and another one of her companions, but there is no entrance. I simply cannot find it. Here is what I did-

1. I selected the mission and fast-traveled to korvanjund.
2. I killed the three bandits waiting there for me
3. I entered the top door and saw legate Rikke and her companion.
4. I looked around the small room and after I saw a walkthrough, the entrance

after I went inside the main door was caved in with rocks and roots. So I left the room to go outside and went back in. It was still blocked off with no entrance. So then I waited a few hours and legate Rikke had somehow found a way in when I was waiting and I have no clue what to do to get in. I'm not sure if I did a previous quest that caved it in or I didn't do something right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused. You started the civil war quests a while ago and never finished because they were time consuming and boring? The Jagged Crown is the first one after joining the legion.

Anyway, this is a bug, the rubble is supposed to be there when not on this quest and cleared away once the quest started. Either because you waited so long or because one of your mods this did not happen.
You can try to either reload a save before coming to Korvanjund and try again or you use the console to bypass the rubble.

**MarkForDelete** may be able to delete the rubble. Target it, enter the command and reenter the dungeon.

**player.moveto 000198BB** should teleport you to Rikke.

Comment: I play on Xbox and yeah I know it was the first quest but it was so boring doing it because clearing out a bandit's place is just time consuming but not that hard.

Comment: Well, with Xbox there is nothing you can do except reloading and hoping that it fixes sometime. It certainly is a bug and all the workarounds are only available on PC.